# How to build authorization based systems with React?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, authentication, reactjs

I'm about to develop a application which will have some pages/components based on the authenticated user authorization/roles/permissions.

First of all: how to avoid having components different of `<Login />` (for example) when a unauthenticated user access the app?

Them how to properly load different sets of components based on user's authorization? For example: only the users with `manager` role would be able to see `<ManageUsers />` component. Only `admins` will see `<Dashboard />` and so on.

This MUST to be handled by the server? I guess.

**How is role-based apps built with React?**
*(and I think the question extends for other client-side frameworks like Angular as well).*

Comment: you probably want to swap out the whole page, not just sections... you also probably don't need a view framework to handle the login page, so you can keep the fancy code naive if it's behind the login...

Comment: So your ideia is to have different apps for each kind of domain/role, within one app to login where it redirects to the authorized app?

Comment: one or more apps on one or more pages, plus one login page that re-directs to the application page(s) after a login. that way, you never even potentially expose the user to something he shouldn't see, and one page reload at the start is not an abomination (think gmail). i find it just makes everything simpler to have a simple login, then transfer to the good stuff. you can connect all the dots with ajax, but reloading (even once) can simplify a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problems either on the server-side or on the client. The main idea is to determine a user status and handle it. For example, you can redirect the user to the login page, show a warning message or allow the user to open the page.

On a server: you determine the user (through cookies, token etc) and his status. If it's okay then pass him on, if not - redirect e.g. to the login page.

About React and other frameworks/libraries: again you need to determine the user status. You can do this by sending API request or getting stored data in localstorage etc. There're several approaches how to do it (the 1st way is better in my opinion):

1. **Through the router.** In a React app you can use [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) and [`onEnter`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replacestate-callback) hook. [Here an example](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-with-shared-root). In short, when route is matched the `onEnter` hook will be called and there you can do whatever you want
2. **By server response.** If it's a SPA then you probably need to load some data to show the page. So, if the user isn't authenticated or can't get this data the server should return 401 (not authenticated/not logged in) or 403 (not authorized) status. And again you just need to handle this.

That's all about allowing a user to open a page. But what about displaying different blocks on the page for different users? Let's say we need to show different set of links in the header for authenticated user and admin. How it might look with React:

```
const Header = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <header>
                <a className="logo" href="/">Logo</a>
                // here you get the user role from the Flux store, localstorage or whatever you want
                {user.role === 'admin' ? this.renderAdminLinks() : this.renderAuthLinks()}
            </header>
        );
    },
    renderAuthLinks() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <a href="app">Dashboard</a>
                <a href="profile">Profile</a>
            </ul>
        );
    },
    renderAdminLinks() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <a href="admin">Admin Panel</a>
                <a href="stats">Statistics</a>
            </ul>
        );
    }
});
```

It's just an example but for more complicated things you can define new components like `<AdminLinks/>`, `<UserLinks>` and so on.

The the same idea will work with Angular/Backbone/etc in the component/view you should decide what you want to show to the user based on his status.

Comment: The problem here is that non-admin users can find out links served for admin by looking at the code. OP asked about loading modules depending on user role, NOT about just choosing which one to use from those already loaded. So non-admin user browser should never receive `renderAdminLinks()` part.